# Numbers divisible by precisely the same set of primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Say two positive integers are "*peers*" if they are divisible by precisely the same set of primes, such as 12 and 18 (both divisible by 2 and 3), or 70 and 350 (both divisible by 2, 5 and 7).

What are the best estimates known for the number of pairwise *non-peers* not greater than an arbitrary positive integer *N*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your count equals the number of square-free numbers up to $N$. This is because a set of positive integers are pairwise "non-peers" if any only if their [radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) are distinct. This is a well-studied problem in analytic number theory, see in particular Walfisz's estimate [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution).

Comment: Now I see it, as the count of pairs is not being asked. Ignore "I'm not seeing this. Nonpeer pairs would include 2^a and 2^b3^c.  If you take (N-1) choose 2 and subtract off the peer pairs, then you get the count Bernardo asks. The number of peer pairs is related to but different from the set of square free numbers. " Gerhard "Or Is Non Peer Different?" Paseman, 2019.09.04.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: The OP is not talking about the number of peer or non-peer pairs. Instead, he is talking about the maximal number of integers one can choose from $\{1,\dots,N\}$ such that no two of them are peers, i.e., no two of them have the same square-free radical. So any good subset $S\subset\{1,\dots,N\}$ gives rise to a subset $T\subset\{1,\dots,N\}$ of square-free integers with $|S|=|T|$. To obtain $T$ from $S$, simply replace each element of $S$ by its radical. The conclusion in my post follows.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Gerhard "Will Try Thinking More Slowly" Paseman, 2019.09.04.